# When I try to create a view in postgres I get "Error: relation datatable does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

```
CREATE VIEW vtable AS

SELECT
datatable.TRANSID,
datatable.DGROUP,
datatable.DEP,
datatable.NEXTD,
othertable.AIR,
othertable.ORIG,
othertable.DE,
thirdtable.FLI

FROM datatable
LEFT JOIN othertable ON datatable.DE = othertable.DE
LEFT JOIN third ON datatable.TRANSID = thirdtable.TRANSID
```

Using the code above, I am trying to create a view table, however it says that the relation doesn't exist. What can I do to solve this?

Update:
I decided to only pull from one table and wrote my code as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW vtable AS
SELECT
Schema1."datatable".TRANSID,
Schema1."datatable".DGROUP,
Schema1."datatable".DEP
FROM Schema1."datatable";
```

It now displayed an error message stating
"ERROR: column "datatable".TRANSID does not exist"

Comment: othertable.DE'  Please remove the quotation mark

Comment: Is this the actual spelling for `datatable`? Or is it some form of mixed(DataTable) or upper(DATATABLE) case? If it is the actual spelling will need to be double quoted, for example `... FROM "DataTable" ...` and anywhere else it is used `"DataTable".TRANSID`.

Comment: The quotation mark by DE was not supposed to be there, sorry. and yes the actual spelling is datatable

Comment: Then you have [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue. In `psql` do `show search_path;`. I'm going to say the schema list it returns does not include the schema `datatable` is in. You either need to modify the `search_path` or schema qualify the table name e.g. `some_schema.datatable`.

Comment: Thank you adrian, I added the "" but despite that I still get the error that my datatable does not exist unfortunately

Comment: Do I modify the search path in psql or can i do it through pgadmin?

Comment: Have you established that `datatable` is in schema that is not in the `search_path`? The best long term solution is to change the setting in `postgresql.conf` and reload the server.

Comment: Can you successfully run `select * from database`, `select * from othertable`, and also `select * from third`?

Comment: yes to the first but no to the second, I cant run those althiugh when I do view/edit data it lets me and the table is in the schema

Comment: @ilraz98 It's a weird case. You can see the second table through a UI interface, but not through command-line SQL. Maybe permissions? Maybe you are using a different user on both sides...

Comment: I checked and Im using the same user, when I write select * from schema."third" then the select statment works, however when I write LEFT JOIN schema."othertable" ON schema."datatable".DE = schema."othertable".DE then it tells me that column datatable.DE doesnt exist. Even though it does

Comment: I doubt `select * from database` worked.  You need to quit posting random query snippets with no context. Also post your queries and results as updates to your question, not in the comments. When you do post include 1) Client used. 2) Complete connection parameters for client. 3) What the schema is that `datatable` is in? 4) What `select * from <schema_name>.datatable yields, where <schema_name> is replaced with the schema. Best guess at this point is you are not connecting to same database via the GUI as you are via the command line.

Comment: Select * from database did work, but only after i stated in which schema it was. So when I wrote select * from Schemas."database" (schemas being the name of the schema in which the table "database" is in) worked. However when I tried using it in a View statement and pulling from only one table as shown above in the update it did not work and would not recognize that the first column "

Comment: Also I apologize for how I post things. I am new here and also under a lot of pressure, but I appreciate you guys helping me out and being patient with me

Comment: Pretty sure `select * from Schemas."database"` was actually `select * from Schemas."datatable"`. Hmm, this error message: `"ERROR: column "datatable".TRANSID does not exist"` does not make sense. You did not quote `TRANSID` so it should show up as `"datatable".transid` in the error. Did you change the message or did you do `"datatable"."TRANSID "`? Also what is the actual spelling in the table?

Comment: Oh yeah no I changed the message, it wrote it as "ERROR:  column datatable.transid does not exist" (sorry i didnt think that was important). the actual table is FACT_TABLE

Comment: And now you know why you are under pressure and are seven hours into a 5-10 minute fix. Attention to detail is everything, rewriting error messages is erasing detail and a very bad idea. The spelling I was looking for was the column name. I'm guessing it is mixed/upper case and per my comment at very beginning that needs to be quoted when used. So I'm guessing it needs to be `Schema1."datatable"."TRANSID"` or whatever the actual spelling for the column is quoted. All of this is good example of why if you have a choice stick to all lower case spellings.